# I am unable to upload images in andriod studio in pubspec.yaml error is attached below please suggest me what to do?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dependencies, android-image

[image]

can anyone tell the reason
 I am unable to upload images in andriod studio in pubspec.yaml error is attached below please suggest me what to do?

Comment: please provide descriptive information. unable to upload is vague description . Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know your error message, I thought you are misguided with an indentation in a pubspec.yamal file. Check once again, you should be very concise, from one heading to another give exactly two spaces.